# How can I set the row height in Tkinter TreeView?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, hidpi

I wrote a small app recently that needs to be cross-platform. I used Python and Tkinter for the GUI.

It works great but recently I got a new laptop with a hiDPI screen and it seems to mess up the TreeView (see image below). The text height is too big compared to the height of the rows.

The picture is taken from a virtual machine running Windows 7 as a guest. I had to set the text to a larger size (125%) to be able to read on the screen (every other program I've tried work fine with this setting).

Is there any way to set the height of a row in Tkinter TreeView? I haven't seen anything like that in the docs.

[image]

Comment: In the future, be sure to include a [mcve]. We can't test a screenshot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=40) # repace 40 with whatever you need
```

Comment: I like answers simple but If you don't could please add working example as well?

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for not including a MCVE, I thought the picture would speak for itself.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin in coding a single character mistake can be the difference between working and not, so we like to be able to test our solutions before we post them. By not including a MCVE, you are putting the burden on us to write some boilerplate code to do the testing. In this case I had an answer already since it's not the first time I've been asked this question. If I hadn't had a ready answer I would not have bothered researching your problem without a way to test solutions.

Comment: @Novel
I have a project with 3 different treeviews, and I have tried to use :
`s= ttk.Style()`
`s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=40)`

But then it changes the row height for all treeviews , not for the treeview that I wanted. I have tried to change the `root` but it didnt work, can you please help me with this?

Comment: @AleksandarBeat Read up on styles. I modified the global style. To do what you want you need to make a style with a new name like `s.configure('Aleksandar.Treeview', rowheight=40)` which you can then use by passing the style argument like `t = ttk.Treeview(self, style='Aleksandar.Treeview')`.

Comment: @Novel i have tryed to do what you told me but I didnt succeed. Please check out this question, tell me if you can help me with it:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169603/changing-row-height-for-different-treeviews-tkitner)

Answer (score 7):

I already have a variable setup for font size and would like to avoid setting up a variable for row height. So my code looks like this:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=(None, LARGE_FONT), \
                rowheight=int(LARGE_FONT*2.5))
style.configure("Treeview", font=(None, MON_FONTSIZE), \
                rowheight=int(MON_FONTSIZE*2.5))
```

When `LARGE_FONT` is set to `14`, the row height is set to `35`. When `MON_FONTSIZE` is set to `12`, the row height is calculated as `30`.

The end result has the correct spacing (IMO) for the system font. YMMV for other font families though:

[image: wman gnome gsettings.png]

Comment: Having experienced a similar problem, this is actually the better solution in my opinion.