# Changing row height for different treeviews tkitner

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 treeviews, and I want to set the row height for first to be 45. Im using `style` but when I change the row height for first treeview , it automatically changes the row height for second treeview.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

myApp = Tk()

#first tree with row height of 45

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=45)

NewTree= ttk.Treeview(myApp, height=4, style='Treeview')
NewTree['show'] = 'headings'

NewTree["columns"]=("1","2")

NewTree.column("1", width=50)
NewTree.column("2", width=50)

NewTree.heading("1", text="Col A")
NewTree.heading("2", text="Col B")

item = NewTree.insert("", "end", values=("value 1","value 2"))

NewTree.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5)

#second tree with defult row height (it automatically changed to 45)
#How to set different row heights to diferent treeviews?

SecondTree= ttk.Treeview(myApp, height=4)
SecondTree['show'] = 'headings'

SecondTree["columns"]=("1","2")

SecondTree.column("1", width=50)
SecondTree.column("2", width=50)

SecondTree.heading("1", text="Col A")
SecondTree.heading("2", text="Col B")

item = SecondTree.insert("", "end", values=("value 1","value 2"))

SecondTree.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Treeview` style is the default style used for all Treeview widgets. If you change that, you change all Treeviews. If you want to change only one Treeview, make a new style based on the default `Treeview` style and alter that ([reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190509211714/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html)):

```
s.configure('MyStyle.Treeview', rowheight=45)

NewTree= ttk.Treeview(myApp, height=4, style='MyStyle.Treeview')
```