# Overlapping Images Treeview python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, treeview

When I try to insert an image into each row in a tk.treeviw, the images overlap. Is their a way of making each row of the treeview have a minimum height, so that the images do not collide? I have created a scrollbar so the treeview is scrollable.

```
PatrolView.insert("", "end", text="", image=RavenImage, values=(i[0], myplname, myaplname, i[3]))
PatrolView.insert("", "end", text="", image=LionImage, values=(i[0], myplname, myaplname, i[3]))
PatrolView.insert("", "end", text="", image=BullImage, values=(i[0], myplname, myaplname, i[3]))
```

Creates this Treeview.
[image: Treeview]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing row height for different treeviews tkitner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51173482/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl Heres what I got so far: `newT=ttk.Style()`
`newT.configure('PViewStyle', rowheight=100)`
`PatrolView = ttk.Treeview(PatrolOverview,style='PViewStyle')` but this yields `_tkinter.TclError: Layout PViewStyle not found`

Comment: The name of the Style follows the rule `PViewStyle.Treeview`. Means **must** end with `.Treeview`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by resizing the image before adding it to the treeview and also change the rowheight attribute

```
style2 = ttk.Style()
style2.theme_use("winnative")

style2.configure("sohof.files.Treeview",
                                 background="#D3D3D3",
                                 foreground="white",
                                 rowheight=int(monitorHeight / 2.5),
                                 fieldbackground="#D3D3D3")


self.secondTreeview = ttk.Treeview(subjectWindowCanvas, selectmode='browse',
                                                   style="sohof.files.Treeview")
```