# How to set the row height of data rows of ttkbootstrap.tableview.Tableview (bootstrap.TableView NOT tk.TreeView)?

Tags: python, tableview, ttkbootstrap

This question is not a duplicate of [How can I set the row height in Tkinter TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432506/how-can-i-set-the-row-height-in-tkinter-treeview) because I am asking about `ttkboostrap.tableview.Tableview` and not `tk.Treeview`. The Treeview solutions do not work for Tableview.

I cannot set the row height of `ttkbootstrap.tableview.Tableview` data rows. I can change the heading but not the data rows.

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.tableview import Tableview
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

app = ttk.Window()
style = app.style
**style.configure('Treeview.Heading', rowheight=80, font=(None, 18))
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=80, font=(None, 18))**

coldata = [{"text": "LNum", "stretch": False}, "CompanyName", {"text": "UserCount", "stretch": False}, ]
rowdata = [('A123', 'IzzyCo', 12), ('A136', 'Kimdee Inc.', 45), ('A158', 'Farmadding Co.', 36)]

dt = Tableview(
    master=app,
    coldata=coldata,
    rowdata=rowdata,
    paginated=True,
    searchable=True
)
dt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, padx=10, pady=10)
dt.load_table_data()
app.mainloop()
```

I expect the data row height to increase in height but it does not.

Comment: Still answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48432749/20851944)!

Comment: My question is about bootstrap.Tableview, the tk.Treeview solutions given do not work for Tableview. If you run the code you will see that row height on Tableview does not get affected.